# How to use leaflet.pattern in sveltekit with leaflet maps

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, svelte, sveltekit

I want to fill my geojson with custom patterns, using leaflet.pattern we can achieve it here is the git repo https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern but when I try to use it in sveltekit it throws the error 'L.pattern is not constructor'
Actually, it is not importing leaflet.pattern correctly

this is my current code

```
<script>
   let mapElement;
   let map;
   let L;
   
   onMount(async () => {
    if (browser) {
        L = await import('leaflet');
        await import('leaflet.pattern');
        map = L.map(mapElement).setView([40.1164, -88.2434], 15);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution:
                '&copy; <a                 href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
   
   // Default Stripes.
          var stripes = new L.StripePattern();
          stripes.addTo(map);
   
          var geojsonFeature = {
              "type": "Feature",
              "properties": {
                  "name": "GeoJson Example Area"
              },
              "geometry": {
                  "type": "Polygon",
                  "coordinates": [[
                      [-120.34, 50.68],
                      [-120.35, 50.68],
                      [-120.35, 50.69],
                      [-120.34, 50.69],
                      [-120.34, 50.68]
                  ]]
              }
          };
   
          L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
              style: {
                  fillPattern: stripes
              }
          }).addTo(map);
   }
   });
   
</script>
<main>
   <div bind:this={mapElement} />
</main>
<style>
   @import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
   main div {
   height: 100vh;
   }
</style>
<main>
   <div bind:this={mapElement} />
</main>
<style>
   @import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
   main div {
   height: 100vh;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this change:

```
<script>
   let mapElement;
   let map;
   let L;
   let LP;
   
   onMount(async () => {
      L = await import('leaflet');
      LP = await import('leaflet.pattern');
      map = L.map(mapElement).setView([40.1164, -88.2434], 15);
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution:
                '&copy; <a                 href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
   
   // Default Stripes.
      var stripes = new LP.StripePattern();
      ...
```

Also there is no need to check for `browser` because `onMount` [only runs in browser](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount).